# child of post type (custom)

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, child-pages, post-type

I registered a custom post type (foo) with `register_post_type`, setting `'hierarchical' => true,`so now when I want to use it I have `post_type=foo`.

How can I query child of foo? any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display child pages of particular parent foo page using following code ( using parent page ID ):

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=foo&post_parent=93' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
$the_query->the_post();
echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: thanks mate, I was looking for all complex solutions but nothing so obvious, thanks a lot!